# Не прилетают данные с бэка, что делать?

Tags: vue.js, flask, развертывание, deploy

Ребят, подскажите в чем ошибка. Первый раз ставлю на сервер проект.
У меня есть фронт написанный на Vue и бэк написанный на Flask.
Есть удаленный сервер, куда через teamViewer я загружаю весь проект. Далее устанавливаю все пакеты.
Запускаю бэк на сервере на сервере http://127.0.0.1:5000, далее на порте 8080 запускаю фронт.
Захожу на сайт, вот его ip http://194.67.31.90:58080/ и пытаюсь получить данные с бэка через API. Данные не приходят. Не понимаю в чем ошибся. Подскажите пожалуйста. Вот мой запрос с фронта на бэк:

Store.js

```
getMaturity_actions({ commit }, underlying) {
            return new Promise(( resolve, reject) => {
                axios({ url: 'http://localhost:5000/maturities', params: {currency: underlying}, method: 'GET'})
                .then(resp => {

                    const data = resp.data.data[underlying]
                    commit('setMaturityList_mutations', data) // Получаем все даты 
                    resolve(resp)
                })
                .catch(resp => {
                    reject(resp)
                })
            })
        },
```

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/maturities` ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот твое решение проблемы!!!!
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS